# Select a range of columns in Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Assuming that I have a Spark Dataframe `df`, how can I select a range of columns e.g. from column 100 to column 200?

Comment: @PrasadKhode This is not a duplicate. The question you have mentioned refers to Scala and not to Python.

Comment: Try `select` and `slice` though.

Comment: @Old-School although the programming language is different, the approach remains d same, pls try the solution given there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `df.columns` returns a `list`, you can slice it and pass it to `select`:

```
df.select(df.columns[99:200])
```

This gets the subset of the `DataFrame` containing the 100th to 200th columns, inclusive.